# how to pass json encoded php variable as parameter in onclick event function in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have my code like this but the jquery is not giving response which writen in the bottom of the page in

```
    <tr><th>Hindu</th>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getIdies('<?php echo json_encode(explode(",",
                     $count[1 ]->OBCHinduOBC)); ?>')"><?php echo $count[1 ]->HinduOBC;?>
            </a></td>
   </tr>
```

This is my jquery

```
<sript>
function getIdies(values){
    $.each(values,function(key,value){
        alert(value);
    });
}
</script>
```

The below  line gives **output** like

```
<?php echo json_encode(explode(",", $count[1 ]->OBCHinduOBC)); ?> 
output:   ["200","500","700","675","54","567","678","867"]
```

Comment: `<sript>` is not the same as `<script>` ...Off-topic: Typo

Answer (score 1):

You are not json decoding before use in our script,to decode the json you can use **$.parseJSON**
Just like this

```
<script>
function getIdies(values) {
    $.each(values, function (key, val) {
        alert(val);
    });
}
```

**Modification**:-
Just change your html to

```
<tr><th>Hindu</th>
    <?php  $ids= json_encode(explode(",",$count[1]->OBCHinduOBC));?>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getIdies({{$ids}})"><?php echo $count[1 ]->HinduOBC;?>
        </a></td>
</tr>
```

Try this it will work fine.

Comment: :Control is not going to function getIdies() when tried using alert() before  $.each(), it is not alerting.

Comment: @Mahantesh i just solved the issue now its working fine, just try this answer again it will work for you.

Comment: its not working tried like this 1) getIdies({{$ids}}) printing html when inspected getIdies({{$ids}})     2)getIdies({{<?php echo $ids; ?>}}) printing html like this  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getIdies({{[" 2152","2179","2165","2189","2182",
"2197","2197","2200","2207","2210","2214","2220","2224","2234","2257","2261","2263",
"2236","2236","2236","2265","2268","2267","2269","2163","2277","2224","2292","2306",
"2306","2311","2310","2220","2224","2224","2315","2277","2321","2390","2398","2398",
"2396","2396"]}})"="">55</a>

Comment: no need of `<?php echo $ids; ?>` just copy the code and past  as it is.means `getIdies({{$ids}}) ` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting explode(",", $count[1 ]->OBCHinduOBC) as a new variable before encoding it with json.